# Java XML DOM Parsing MathML

Tags: java, xml, dom, recursion, binary-tree

The short of it is, I need help in figuring out how I can make this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" display="inline" overflow="scroll" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML http://www.w3.org/Math/XMLSchema/mathml2/mathml2.xsd">
<mml:apply>
    <mml:plus/>
    <mml:apply>
        <mml:plus/>
        <mml:cn>398.00</mml:cn>
        <mml:apply>
            <mml:times/>
            <mml:cn>398.00</mml:cn>
            <mml:cn>0.10</mml:cn>
        </mml:apply>
    </mml:apply>
    <mml:apply>
        <mml:plus/>
        <mml:cn>18</mml:cn>
        <mml:apply>
            <mml:plus/>
            <mml:cn>10</mml:cn>
            <mml:cn>12.40</mml:cn>
        </mml:apply>
    </mml:apply>
</mml:apply>
```

Do a calculation like this:
398.00 + (398 * .10) + 18 + 10 + 12.40

Writing in Java, I'm parsing the DOM to grab these tag names and the numeric values, but I'm having difficulty writing an algorithm that will do this efficiently. 
I'm thinking something with recursion might work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, recursion can do it:

extract your nodes at first level, and iterate

if is is mml:cn : it a number: done

If it is mml:plus:

- extract the two next ones: mml:apply
- for each one, make the calculation at this level
- then do a plus operation
- and you can also printf (calcul1 + calcul2) where calcul1 is result of printf of first mml:apply, etc.

if is mmt:times: same thing with multiply

etc.